# How to retrive data from json in codename one?

Tags: json, codenameone

I am alble to print the data of json in this way:

```
[
    {"id":"9","location":"All Nepal"},
    {"id":"16","location":"BIRATNAGAR"},
    {"id":"11","location":"Birtamod"},
    {"id":"19","location":"Boudha"},
    {"id":"14","location":"DAMAK"},
    {"id":"17","location":"DHARAN"},
    {"id":"10","location":"Dhulabari"},
    {"id":"15","location":"ITAHARI"},
    {"id":"1","location":"Kathmandu"},
    {"id":"18","location":"LAHAN"},
    {"id":"8","location":"Narayanghat"},
    {"id":"7","location":"Pokhara"}
]
```

But i want this all data to show in different list. I have saved all the data to a HashTable but not able to retrive that data in the list.

Comment: Maybe you get more help if you provide an example output and showed us the code of what you tried to do. As it is now, I'd close this questions as being too broad, too unspecific, leaving us guessing.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here in the discussion forum: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/XoUPe71iZ0U/i1sJOg6eEAAJ